# Django - Search field

Tags: javascript, sql, django, google-places-api

I am working on creating a real estate web app. I want to know which is the best implementation to set up my location search field.

I have the Places API up and running (autocompleting with location suggestions), but I am a bit lost now, on how I can retrieve the the information and return filter properties based on the user's preferred location.

1. Should I go with custom SQL query? (I am using posgres)
   2)Is there any established way to do that with google places/map API or any other?

I tried to make it with Django's built in icontains method but my search field returns something like: {London, UK,    } which means many words separated with comma and icontains does not work that way.

Happy for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to split the query to country, state, district, street...

```
query = "London, UK"
country = query.split(",")[-1]
state = query.split(",")[-2]
```

After that, you can pass the country to Django models filter

```
result = some_model.objects.all().filter(country__icontains=country)
```

Comment: Nice approach but I need to match as many details as possible. Oxford city for example exists in both UK and US. The ideal it would be to take the values {Chester, CH1 3DA, United Kingdom} generated from places API  and match them with the listed properties which have location field with all the details stored.

Comment: Then, you can keep using "filter" for all the values you are receiving from places API (starting from country to the street). For example, some_model.objects.all().filter(address__icontains=country).filter(address__icontains=state).filter(address__icontains=street)